# Vertical orientation landscape page in a PDF output file

Tags: pdf, rotating, landscape, lscape

I'm using the `lscape` environment to produce landscape pages in my LaTeX document for pages that have large figures or tables, so that my page numbering is in the right place when it comes to printing etc.  However, the `\begin{landscape} ... \end{landscape}` code has the consequence of putting the landscape pages as landscape in the PDF document, when all the other pages are in the portrait orientation.

Is there a way to have the landscape pages put in the same orientation as the rest of the pages in the document for the PDF output?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Title 1}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
Text here.
\end{landscape}
\chapter{Title 2}
\end{document}
```

The above code outputs to a pdf as shown on the left of the image below, I would like to achieve the output shown on the right.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: well actually it _doesn't_ do that (pdflscape does which is the main difference) however some pdf viewers autimatically detect the orientation of "most" text and rotate the page view (they may have an option not to do that, acrobat does for example)

Comment: I've tried using the `pdflscape` package with the `\begin{landscape} ...\end{landscape}` commands, but it doesn't seem to change anything for me.  I'm compiling using LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF in TexMaker.  Would that have any effect?

Comment: if you use pdflscape there are view rotate instructions inserted in the page, if you use the original lscape there should not be, what happens if you look at the generated pdf in other pdf viewers, is that page always rotated?

Answer (score 31):

`\usepackage{lscape}` - no rotation of the page

`\usepackage{pdflscape}` - automatic rotation of the page

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Having pointed the difference of the packages is very good. However, it would be great if you could extend your answer highlighting with a concrete example how they work. You may want to use canonical [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/13304) for this.

Comment: Honestly, this answer is enough. MWE produces the exact same output as in the question.

Comment: `\usepackage{pdflscape}` works for me!

Answer (score 4):

The package `rotating` (described on [LaTeX WikiBooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rotations) and [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/rotating)) provides several environments (including `sidewaysfigure` and `sidewaystable`) enabling you to have a float on its own page rotated with respect to the normal headers and page numbering.  The figure and caption are both rotated 90 degrees.  These environments do force the float to its own page, however.

As an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Used for illustration purposes
\usepackage{rotating} % Provides {sideways}{sidewaysfigure}{sidewaystable} environments
\begin{document}

\Huge
\section{Non-Rotated Figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{demo.jpg}
\caption{Upright Figure}
\end{figure}

\section{Rotated Figure on Next Page}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{demo.jpg}
\caption{Sideways Figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

gives the output you desire:

[image: Two Pages SidewaysFigure Environment]