# How to remove a blank page between a landscape and a portrait pages

Tags: blank-page

I am using an article class document for my thesis.
I have created on of the tables in a landscape format and the next table on a portrait page, however, I am getting an empty page between them.

How can I remove it?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You need to not do whatever you did to cause the blank page to be added, but if you don't say what that is it is hard for us to say what not to do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Scratching my head while reading your comment ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It is a brain twister ;)

Comment: @HarishKumar: Rather a tongue-twister, if reading loud ;-)

Comment: Perhaps related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164514/47522

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am using \documentclass{article} and created a longtable using landscape format. The next page contains another table but the page is in a portrait format. When converting it to PDF, I get an empty page between the tables (the one on the landscape and the one on the portrait). The empty page is in a landscape format. How can I delete it. I did not use the command \newpage between the tables

Comment: @Fatema: Please add a minimal working example in the editor where you posted your question, as you were asked already once.